# How can I make my app search an existing UITableView for values selected in a UIPickerView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, view, xcode4.5, uipickerview

So I've developed an app that currently has a populated UITableView. The UITableView is currently populated with data from a MySQL database. The UITableView also contains a working Search Bar.

However to add to this, we now want to add a 3 column UIPickerView to the mix (already coded).

**The idea:** Users select 3 values (one from each column), and hit a "GO" button. Once they've selected their values and pressed GO, we want the app to filter through the uitableview, and only show results that contain the values they selected in the PickerView.

Everything is coded, I'm just not sure how to connect the two. How would I go about doing this? I've pasted our code so far below (apologies for the lengthy post, but it all seems valid in this case). Any help is much appreciated.

**ViewController.h** (TABLEVIEW CONTROLLER)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITableView *strainTableView;

NSArray *Strains;
NSArray *searchResults;

NSMutableData *data;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *searchResults;



@end
```

**ViewController.m** (TABLEVIEW CONTROLLER)

```
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview

{

    return 1;

}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];




    } else {
        return [Strains count];

    }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *strainTableIdentifier = @"StrainTableCell";

    StrainTableCell *cell = (StrainTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 


        cell = [[StrainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];



        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StrainTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {


        cell.titleLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
        cell.ratingLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];


        NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);
    } else {
        cell.titleLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
         cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
         cell.ratingLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];



    }

    {

    } 


return cell;

}


- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [Strains filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];


}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString 
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    StrainDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[StrainDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StrainDetailViewController" bundle:nil]; if ([searchResults count]) {

        detailViewController.title = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        detailViewController.strainDetail = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {

        detailViewController.title = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        detailViewController.strainDetail = [Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@", Strains);
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

**PickerViewController.h**

```
@interface PickerViewController : UIViewController {


    UIPickerView *pickerView;

    NSMutableArray *array1;
    NSMutableArray *array2;
    NSMutableArray *array3;



    NSArray *Strains;
    NSArray *searchResults;

    NSMutableData *data;


    }

    - (IBAction)buttonpressed:(UIButton *)sender;

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;



        - (void)populateArray1;
        - (void)populateArray2;
        - (void)populateArray3;

    @end



**PickerViewController.m**


    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark picker view methods
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
    {
        return 3;
    }

    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        if (component == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"you selected %@", [array1 objectAtIndex:row]);

        }

        if (component == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"you selected %@", [array2 objectAtIndex:row]);

        }


        if (component == 2)
        {
            NSLog(@"you selected %@", [array3 objectAtIndex:row]);

        }



    }


    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    {




        if (component == 0)
        {
            return [array1 count];
        }

        if (component == 1)
        {
            return [array2 count];
        }


        if (component == 2)
        {
            return [array3 count];
        }

        else
        {
            return [array1 count];
        }
    }

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    {

        if (component == 0)
        {
            return [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
        }

        if (component == 1)
        {
            return [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
        }

        if (component == 2)
        {
            return [array3 objectAtIndex:row];
        }

        else
        {
            return [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
        }
    }



    - (void)populateArray1
    {
        array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [array1 addObject:@"Arthritis"];
        [array1 addObject:@"Cancer"];
        [array1 addObject:@"HIV"];
        [array1 addObject:@"Migraines"];
        [array1 addObject:@"Insomnia"];

    }

    - (void)populateArray2
    {
        array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [array2 addObject:@"Nausea"];
        [array2 addObject:@"Pain"];
        [array2 addObject:@"Appetite"];
        [array2 addObject:@"Fever"];
        [array2 addObject:@"Exhaustion"];

    }

    - (void)populateArray3
    {
        array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [array3 addObject:@"Oil"];
        [array3 addObject:@"Plant"];
        [array3 addObject:@"Edible"];
        [array3 addObject:@"Powder"];


    }


 - (IBAction)buttonpressed:(UIButton *)sender {

        NSLog(@"Button Pushed!");

    NSPredicate *TitlePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Title contains[cd] %@", [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];

    NSPredicate *descriptionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Description contains[cd] %@", [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];

    NSPredicate *ratingpredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Rating contains[cd] %@", [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];

    NSCompoundPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: TitlePredicate,descriptionPredicate,ratingpredicate, nil]];

                                           filterResults = [Strains filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];


}


    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use compound predicate to filter on multiple values

> NSPredicate *TitlePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Title
>   contains[cd] %@", tittletex];
>
> NSPredicate *descriptionPredicate = [NSPredicate
>   predicateWithFormat:@"Description contains[cd] %@", descriptiontext];
>
> NSPredicate *ratingpredicate = [NSPredicate
>   predicateWithFormat:@"Rating contains[cd] %@", ratingtext];
>
> NSCompoundPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate
>   andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>   TitlePredicate,descriptionPredicate,ratingpredicate];
>
> searchResults = [Strains filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

Comment: So instead of having the picker search for titletext, descriptiontext, and rating text, what code could I put in those places to get it to search/filter only for the 3 results selected in the picker? Thanks :)

Comment: I've updated the code in my original post. See what I've replaced it with so far [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:x]